# How to group rows together based on conditions from a list? Pandas

Tags: pandas, database, group-by

I want to be able to group rows into one if they have matching values in certain columns, however I only want them to be grouped if the value is in a list. For example,

```
team_sports = ['football', 'basketball']

view of df

country    sport      age
USA       football    21
USA       football    28
USA       golf        20
USA       golf        44
China     football    30
China     basketball  22
China     basketball  41

wanted outcome
country    sport      age
USA       football    21,28
USA       golf        20
USA       golf        44
China     football    30
China     basketball  22,41

The attempt I made was,

team_sports = ['football', 'basketball']

for i in df['Sport']:
  if i in team_sports:
     group_df= df.groupby(['Country', 'Sport'])['Age'].apply(list).reset_index()
```

This is taking forever to run, the database I'm using has 100,000 rows.

Really appreciate any help, thanks

Comment: Why are you doing it over and over. Doesn’t `group_df= df.groupby(['Country', 'Sport'])['Age'].apply(list).reset_index()` give you the expected result the first time?

Comment: @HenryEcker I'm not sure what you mean, but I put in a for so it does not group together rows of different sports, for the example above, golf. Please correct me if I misinterpreted.

Comment: I see, I missed the part about only grouping the rows in the list. Does the order matter? do you need them to be in the order they appear or order doesn't matter as long as all results are present?

Comment: @HenryEcker Order does not matter, as long the result is there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The more straightforward approach is to separate the DataFrame based on those rows where the `sports` column [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) the list of `team_sports`. [`groupby aggregate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.aggregate.html) separately then [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) back together:

```
team_sports = ['football', 'basketball']

m = df['sport'].isin(team_sports)
cols = ['country', 'sport']
group_df = pd.concat([
    # Group those that do match condition
    df[m].groupby(cols, as_index=False)['age'].agg(list),
    # Leave those that don't match condition as is
    df[~m]
], ignore_index=True).sort_values(cols)
```

*[`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) is optional to regroup country and sport together

`group_df`:

```
  country       sport       age
0   China  basketball  [22, 41]
1   China    football      [30]
2     USA    football  [21, 28]
3     USA        golf        20
4     USA        golf        44
```

---

The less straightforward approach would be to create a new grouping level based on whether or not a value is in the list of team sports using [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) + [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
team_sports = ['football', 'basketball']

group_df = (
    df.groupby(
        ['country', 'sport',
         (~df['sport'].sort_values().isin(team_sports)).cumsum().sort_index()],
        as_index=False,
        sort=False
    )['age'].agg(list)
)
```

`group_df`:

```
  country       sport       age
0     USA    football  [21, 28]
1     USA        golf      [20]
2     USA        golf      [44]
3   China    football      [30]
4   China  basketball  [22, 41]
```

How the groups are created:

```
team_sports = ['football', 'basketball']

print(pd.DataFrame({
    'country': df['country'],
    'sport': df['sport'],
    'not_in_team_sports': (~df['sport'].sort_values()
                           .isin(team_sports)).cumsum().sort_index()
}))
```

```
  country       sport  not_in_team_sports
0     USA    football                   0
1     USA    football                   0
2     USA        golf                   1  # golf 1
3     USA        golf                   2  # golf 2 (not in the same group)
4   China    football                   0
5   China  basketball                   0
6   China  basketball                   0
```

*`sort_values` is necessary here so that `sport` groups are not interrupted by sports that are not in the list.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'country': ['USA', 'USA', 'USA'],
    'sport': ['football', 'golf', 'football'],
    'age': [21, 28, 20]
})
team_sports = ['football', 'basketball']

print(pd.DataFrame({
    'country': df['country'],
    'sport': df['sport'],
    'not_sorted': (~df['sport'].isin(team_sports)).cumsum(),
    'sorted': (~df['sport'].sort_values()
                           .isin(team_sports)).cumsum().sort_index()
}))
```

```
  country     sport  not_sorted  sorted
0     USA  football           0       0
1     USA      golf           1       1
2     USA  football           1       0  # football 1 (separate group if not sorted)
```

Sorting ensures that football go together so this does not happen

---

Setup:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'country': ['USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'China', 'China', 'China'],
    'sport': ['football', 'football', 'golf', 'golf', 'football', 'basketball',
              'basketball'],
    'age': [21, 28, 20, 44, 30, 22, 41]
})
```